# Passing an anonymous variable by reference

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, anonymous

Standard C++ types such as int or char have ctors, so you can have expressions like:

```
int a = int(67); // create anonymous variable and assing it to variable a
int b(13);       // initialize variable b
int(77);         // create anonymous variable
```

User defined types (structures or classes) are able to do the same:

```
struct STRUCT
{
  STRUCT(int a){}
};

STRUCT c = STRUCT(67);
STRUCT d(13);
STRUCT(77);
```

The question is: why can we pass by a reference anonymous structure or class instances, but can not pass standard types?

```
struct STRUCT
{
  STRUCT(int a){}
};

void func1(int& i){}
void func2(STRUCT& s){}
void func3(int i){}
void func4(STRUCT s){}

void main()
{
  //func1(int(56));  // ERROR: C2664
  func2(STRUCT(65)); // OK: anonymous object is created then assigned to a reference
  func3(int(46));    // OK: anonymous int is created then assigned to a parameter
  func4(STRUCT(12)); // OK: anonymous object is created then assigned to a parameter
}
```

Comment: Your `func2` line shouldn't compile (for the same reason as the first).

Comment: `void main()` is non-standard.

Comment: With an appropriate warning level, you will get `warning C4239: nonstandard extension used : 'argument' : conversion from 'STRUCT' to 'STRUCT &'; A non-const reference may only be bound to an lvalue`. You should be using `/W4`.

Comment: @n.m. Maybe we need to say non-standard for such things, it’s misleading. C++/CLI is non-standard. `void main` is wrong.

Comment: @n.m. that just tells how good the code in question was tested for c++ standard conformance :)

Comment: thanks! but doesn't void main() simply mean that program is not returning a value to calling environment and will act as a procedure instead.

Comment: The standard says `it shall have a return type of type int`. Not a lot of freedom here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your compiler allows this, then it's not a standard compatible C++ compiler. You can not bind a temporary rvalue to a non-const lvalue reference. It's the rule. Both [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/acfdf47d2edf574f) and [gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73db08a665558e1b) don't compile that code for `func2(STRUCT(65));`.

Instead you have alternatives:

```
void func1(int&& i){}

void func1(const int& i){}
```

Legacy from C++03: A (lvalue) reference to a non-const type (`int &i`) supposed to able to change the parameter then passing a temporary object such as `56` is not logical because it not changeable. A reference to a const type (`const int &i`) supposed to just observe the value as read-only, then passing a temporary value such as `52` is legal.

In C++11 you can reference to a non-const temporary object by `&&`.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you are using MS VC++ compiler that has such bug.:) You have to bind temporary object with const reference. For example you may write

```
const int &ri = 10;
```

but you may not write

```
int &ri = 10;
```

The same is valid for user-defined types.

```
const STRUCT &rs = STRUCT( 10 );

STRUCT &rs = STRUCT( 10 ); // the compiler shall issue an error.
```

Answer (score 0):

In c++,an anonymous temporary object is always a right-value.To accept an right-value as argument,you can:

1).void foo1(TYPE);         //passing by value
2).void foo2(const TYPE &); //passing by const reference
3).void foo3(TYPE &&);      //in c++11,passing by right-value reference

Your "func3" and "func4" accept an argument that passed by value,it's ok.
However,"func1" and "func2" can only accept an argument that passed by a left-value reference.So it's wrong to pass an anonymous parameter.